# Function to convert strings from hmmss, mmss, ss format to milliseconds

Tags: javascript, parsing, datetime, unit-conversion

Here's the current logic to convert strings in the format `hh:mm:ss`, `mm:ss` or `ss` to milliseconds.

Any comments on how to improve this?

```
hhmmssToMillis(hhmmss) {
   let time= hhmmss.split(':').reverse();
   let millis = 0;
   switch(time.length) {
     case 1: 
         millis = parseInt(time[0]) * 1000;
         break;
     case 2: 
         millis = (parseInt(time[1]) * 60 + parseInt(time[0])) * 1000;
         break;
     case 3: 
         millis = (parseInt(time[2]) * 60 * 60 + parseInt(time[1]) * 60 + parseInt(time[0])) * 1000;
         break;
   } 
   return millis; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/196370/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Use `const` instead of `let` if the variable is not being reassigned.

You can do away with the `millis` variable if you return early throughout the `switch` statement. This also allows you to remove the `break` statements.

```
hhmmssToMillis(hhmmss) {
    const time = hhmmss.split(':').reverse();
    switch(time.length) {
       case 1: 
         return parseInt(time[0]) * 1000;
       case 2: 
         return (parseInt(time[1]) * 60 + parseInt(time[0])) * 1000;
       case 3: 
         return (parseInt(time[2]) * 60 * 60 + parseInt(time[1]) * 60 + parseInt(time[0])) * 1000;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- your code is missing the `function` keyword - presumably that was omitted accidentally
- the variable `time` is an array of strings - so something like `parts` or `timeParts` might be more descriptive, and because it doesn't get re-assigned, you can use `const` (as was mentioned in [the answer by Glinkis](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/196431/120114)) to avoid accidental re-assignment
- "***Always specify a radix***"<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#ECMAScript_5_removes_octal_interpretation)</sup> when using `parseInt()` (presumably `10`)
- The reverse of the array could be eliminated if items are removed from the array using [`array.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

While it may be slower due to a loop and function call, see a rewrite below using a `while` loop:

```js
function hhmmssToMillis(hhmmss) {
   const parts = hhmmss.split(':');
   if (parts.length > 3) {
     return 0;
   }
   let seconds = 0;
   while (parts.length) {
    seconds += parseInt(parts.shift(), 10) *  60 ** parts.length;
   }
   return seconds * 1000; 
}

console.log(hhmmssToMillis('53'));
console.log(hhmmssToMillis('15:46'));
console.log(hhmmssToMillis('10:14:22'));
console.log(hhmmssToMillis('4:00'));
```

And that `while` loop could be transformed into a `for` loop:

```js
function hhmmssToMillis(hhmmss) {
   const parts = hhmmss.split(':');
   if (parts.length > 3) {
     return 0;
   }
   for(var seconds = 0; parts.length > 0; ) {
    seconds += parseInt(parts.shift(), 10) *  60 ** parts.length;
   }
   return seconds * 1000; 
}

console.log(hhmmssToMillis('53'));
console.log(hhmmssToMillis('15:46'));
console.log(hhmmssToMillis('10:14:22'));
```

While it may be slower, you could also use a functional approach, using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
function hhmmssToMillis(hhmmss) {
   const parts = hhmmss.split(':');
   if (parts.length > 3) {
     return 0;
   }
   const reducer = (acc, cur, idx, arr) => {
     return acc + parseInt(cur, 10) * (60 ** (arr.length - idx - 1)); 
   };
   return parts.reduce(reducer, 0) * 1000;
}

console.log(hhmmssToMillis('53'));
console.log(hhmmssToMillis('15:46'));
console.log(hhmmssToMillis('10:14:22'));
```

And borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17103893/1575353) to [a nearly identical SO Post (but without working code by OP)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9640266/1575353), [Date.UTC()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) could also be used, though apparently that technique [proves slower according to these jsPerf comparison tests](https://jsperf.com/stringstomillis).

```js
function hhmmssToMillis(time)
{
    const parts = time.split(':');    
    return Date.UTC(1970, 0, 1, parts.length > 2?parts[0]: 0, parts.length > 1? parts[0]:0, parts[parts.length - 1]);
}

console.log(hhmmssToMillis('53'));
console.log(hhmmssToMillis('15:46'));
console.log(hhmmssToMillis('10:14:22'));
```

Comment: Using a `while` loop with a fixed multiplier of 60 is wrong. It would also accept `1:1:1:1:1`.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention. I have updated the samples

Comment: Actually @RolandIllig using 60 works as long as the last element has an exponent of `0` because [any +0 value to 0th power is 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19955996/1575353) (even though technically [\$0^0\$ is indeterminate](https://medium.com/i-math/the-zero-power-rule-explained-449b4bd6934d))

Comment: Classical misunderstanding. I meant "using 60 only works as the multiplier for minutes and hours, but not for days, where it would have to be approximately 24".